# Setting maxDate for Tempus Dominus datetime picker causing incorrect time selection

Tags: momentjs, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I have an issue using the [Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4](https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Usage/) datetime picker and setting the *maxDate* option after the picker is initialized. The time changes to **11:58 pm** when I select the newly set maxDate.
The goal is to set the maxDate to the end of day on *12-Mar-2022*.

```
var minDate = moment("2022-03-05").startOf('day').toDate();
var maxDate = moment("2022-03-12").endOf('day').toDate();
```

The code snippet can be run to see the issue in the scenarios below.

**Scenario - Date 1**
Upon initialization, the min and max dates are set.
*Results:* Datepicker works as expected. If the first date selected is the max date of 12-Mar-2022, the time remains as the current time.

**Scenario - Date 2**
Upon initialization, no min and max dates are set. This datetime picker will be used to trigger ***Date 3***.

**Scenario - Date 3**
Upon initialization, only the min date is set. On change of ***Date 2*** (can select any date, selected not used) the max date for ***Date 3*** is set to 12-Mar-2022.
*Results:* Time issue with datetime picker. If the first date selected is the max date of 12-Mar-2022, the time changes to 11:58 pm.

**Scenario - Date 4**
Upon initialization, only the min date is set. Before any date is selected, on click of a button, the max date for ***Date 4*** is set to 12-Mar-2022.
*Results:* Time issue with datetime picker. If the first date selected is the max date of 12-Mar-2022, the time changes to 11:58 pm.

[image]

**Expectation:** Even though maxDate is set for ***Date 3*** and ***Date 4*** after initialization, it should work the same as ***Date 1*** and the time should not go to 11:58 pm.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.0/moment.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.39.0/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-k6/Bkb8Fxf/c1Tkyl39yJwcOZ1P4cRrJu77p83zJjN2Z55prbFHxPs9vN7q3l3+tSMGPDdoH51AEU8Vgo1cgAA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.39.0/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-3JRrEUwaCkFUBLK1N8HehwQgu8e23jTH4np5NHOmQOobuC4ROQxFwFgBLTnhcnQRMs84muMh0PnnwXlPq5MGjg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br />
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                        Date 1:
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"
                            data-toggle="datetimepicker" />
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br />
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
                        Date 2:
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2"
                            data-toggle="datetimepicker" />
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br />
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker3" data-target-input="nearest">
                        Date 3:
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker3"
                            data-toggle="datetimepicker" />
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker3" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br />
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker4" data-target-input="nearest">
                        Date 4:
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker4"
                            data-toggle="datetimepicker" />
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker4" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="setMax" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Set Max for Date 4</button>

            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var minDate = moment("2022-03-05").startOf('day').toDate();
                var maxDate = moment("2022-03-12").endOf('day').toDate();
                //var maxDate;
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                        format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a",
                        useCurrent: false,
                        minDate: minDate,
                        maxDate: maxDate,
                        sideBySide: true
                    });

                    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                        format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a",
                        useCurrent: false,
                        sideBySide: true
                    });

                    $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                        format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a",
                        useCurrent: false,
                        minDate: minDate,
                        sideBySide: true
                    });

                    $('#datetimepicker2').on("change.datetimepicker", (e) => {
                        $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker("maxDate", maxDate);
                    });

                    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
                        format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a",
                        useCurrent: false,
                        minDate: minDate,
                        sideBySide: true
                    });

                    $('#setMax').on("click", (e) => {
                        $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker("maxDate", maxDate);
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```